# expand search wrapper on focus of search input

Tags: html, css, animation

I am working on the frontend of an application where search is the most important action a user can take. Because of this, I want search located at the bottom so that it is [reachable with the thumb.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq8aR.jpg)

The UI I have in mind is nice and meets all my needs, I just don't know how to make it a reality with HTML and CSS. Here's how it looks:

[image: search interaction]

Using HTML and CSS how can I, upon `:focus` on the input -> expand the search bubble at the bottom to take the whole page and move things to the top in a nice animated way?

I have created a [codepen of the initial state](https://codepen.io/Ciwan/pen/poJzaOr) and a little bit of the change to the second state, here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="search">
  <h1 class="search__heading">Search</h1>
  <input type="text" placeholder="type name" class="search__input" />
  <ul class="search_recents">
    <li class="search_recent-item">
      <img class="search_recent-image" src="https://placehold.it/60x60" alt="person image" />
    </li>

    <li class="search_recent-item">
      <img class="search_recent-image" src="https://placehold.it/60x60" alt="person image" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

ul,ol {
  list-style: none;
}

html,body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #5B5847;
}

.search {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #7B796B;
  padding: 1.25em;
  margin: 0 1.25em 1.25em 1.25em;
  border-radius: 10px;

  &:focus-within {
   position: static;
   margin: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 100%;
  }
}

.search__heading {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.search__input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.25em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

.search_recents {
  display: flex;  
}

.search_recent-item {
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}

.search_recent-image {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Is there a way I can show and hide the arrow?

Comment: A little jQuery here wouldn't hurt. This is difficult as the need is to expand the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

For the animation you could do it like down here. For a smooth animation I think a fixed height helps (but not sure if this is what you want)

```
 .search {
  position: fixed;
  height: 225px;
  width: calc(100vw - 2.5em);
  bottom: 1.25rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #7B796B;
  padding: 1.25em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;

  &:focus-within {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: a fixed height? how would that work across various devices? surely it wouldn't!

Comment: Sometimes it can be done if it's content will remain static and it will be sure the height will never increase and is that small it will fit (225px isn't much). But ok, If we're talking about various devices/ cross browser support: https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Afocus-within ...

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to trigger the expansion with a hover on the immediate parent element `.search`. Usability will be fine because the cursor will still be over the element even as the user type. If you like the approach, adjust the transition as needed.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

ul,ol {
  list-style: none;
}

html,body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #5B5847;
}

.search {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #7B796B;
  padding: 1.25em;
  margin: 0 1.25em 1.25em 1.25em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all .8s;

  &:focus-within {
   position: static;
   margin: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 100%;
  }
}

.search__heading {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.search__input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.25em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

.search_recents {
  display: flex;  
}

.search_recent-item {
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}

.search_recent-image {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* my Code starts here */

.search:hover {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: -20px;
    border-radius: 0;
    transition: all .8s;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <h1 class="search__heading">Search</h1>
  <input type="text" placeholder="type name" class="search__input" />
  <ul class="search_recents">
    <li class="search_recent-item">
      <img class="search_recent-image" src="https://placehold.it/60x60" alt="person image" />
    </li>

    <li class="search_recent-item">
      <img class="search_recent-image" src="https://placehold.it/60x60" alt="person image" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*This method, however, creates a problem. You have to find a way to manage the size of the parent element to avoid accidental triggers. It is doable though.